# how to stop the growing tree in C when BFS search element is equal to given input

Tags: c

Assume the inputs are

a = [2,3,4,1]
b = [1,2,4,3]

The function **DoThis** takes the first input and gives the following output.

```
3,2,4,1,
2,4,3,1,
2,3,1,4,
1,3,4,2
```

The DoThis function is as follows:

```
int **DoThis(int n, int arr[n]){
    int l = n;
    int **b = malloc(l * sizeof(*b));//sizeof(*b) : sizeof(int *)
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        j = (i + 1) % l;
        int *copy = malloc(l * sizeof(*copy));//sizeof(int)
        for (k = 0; k < l; k++)
            copy[k] = arr[k];
        int t = copy[i];
        copy[i] = copy[j];
        copy[j] = t;
        //printf("{%d, %d, %d, %d}\n", copy[0], copy[1], copy[2], copy[3]);
        b[i] = copy;
    }
    return b;
}
```

This function will be then performed on all the output produced at first level and so on, until the input . So it will look like this.

[image]

Since we found [1,2,4,3], we stop the function and output as 2, as it is in level 2.

How can I do this??

Comment: You are not using `free` anywhere, is that because you forgot to?

Comment: @iharob Maybe because the OP returns the pointer to the allocated data, so it can be free'd somewhere else?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg absolutely true, I didn't see that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct element {
    int *array;
    int size;
} Element;

bool Element_equal(Element *a, Element *b){
    return a->size == b->size && memcmp(a->array, b->array, a->size * sizeof(*a->array))==0;
}
Element *E_copy(Element *e){
    Element *el = malloc(sizeof(*el));
    el->array = malloc(e->size * sizeof(*e->array));
    memcpy(el->array, e->array, e->size * sizeof(*e->array));
    el->size  = e->size;
}
void E_print(Element *e){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<e->size; i++)
        printf("%d ", e->array[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
void E_drop(Element *e){
    free(e->array);
    free(e);
}

typedef struct node {
    Element *data;
    int level;
    struct node *next;
} Node;

void Node_drop(Node *node){
    E_drop(node->data);
    free(node);
}

typedef struct queque {
    Node *top;
    Node *tail;
} Queque;

Queque *Q_new(void){
    return calloc(1, sizeof(Queque));
}
Node *Q_deq(Queque *q){
    if(q->top){
        Node *node = q->top;
        q->top = q->top->next;
        return node;
    }
    return NULL;
}
void Q_drop(Queque *q){
    Node *node;
    while(node = Q_deq(q))
        Node_drop(node);
    free(q);
}
void Q_enq(Queque *q, Element *element, int level){
    Node *node  = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    node->data  = element;
    node->level = level;
    node->next  = NULL;
    q->tail = q->top ? (q->tail->next = node) : (q->top = node);
}

Element **transpose(Element *e){
    int l = e->size;
    Element **b = malloc(l * sizeof(*b));
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        j = (i + 1) % l;
        Element *copy = E_copy(e);
        int t = copy->array[i];
        copy->array[i] = copy->array[j];
        copy->array[j] = t;
        b[i] = copy;
    }
    return b;
}

int Cyc_Ken_Tau(Element *start, Element *goal){
    Queque *queque = Q_new();
    Q_enq(queque, E_copy(start), 0);//level 0

    while(true){
        Node *node = Q_deq(queque);
        if(Element_equal(node->data, goal)){
            int ret = node->level;
            Node_drop(node);
            Q_drop(queque);
            return ret;
        }
        Element **new_list = transpose(node->data);
        int i;
        for(i=0; i < node->data->size; ++i){
            Q_enq(queque, new_list[i], node->level + 1);
        }
        free(new_list);
        Node_drop(node);
    }
}

int main(){
    int a[] = {2, 3, 4, 1};
    int b[] = {1, 2, 4, 3};
    int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a);
    Element start = { a, n };
    Element goal  = { b, n };
    int level = Cyc_Ken_Tau(&start, &goal);

    printf("%d\n", level);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does `Element_equal()` return the correct result if `a->size` is not equal to `b->size`?

Comment: @MikeofSST Size is assumed to be the same. I did not think about versatility. I'll fix.

Comment: @BLUEPIX Can I simply call you god?

Comment: @MikeofSST A --> size is always equal to b--> size in my test matrix

Comment: @BLUEPIXY How will I edit this program in such a way that the user can input the arrays a and b? Something like user enters the length of arrays ( which are same), then enters arrays a and b?

Comment: @AnakataAndrese Example to enter the array of unknown size to the user there are many in Stackoverflow. The basic idea, input in a loop to secure with `malloc` if caused to enter the pre-size. To enlarge an array by `realloc` as needed if it does not enter the size.

Comment: But I know the size in advance. So I added something like [this](http://pastebin.com/X0NL52sp) in in stead of hardcoding a and b arrays. But "Compilation failed".

Comment: @AnakataAndrese  It can not be affirmed because the error message has not been presented in the fragment of code.... 1)`i` and `size` has not been declared. 2) use the C99  (or C99 mode) supported compiler.

Comment: It worked now. Silly mistakes. But if I have input arrays of say length >10, then the program hangs. No errors, but it hangs.

Comment: @AnakataAndrese I can not certainly judgment is it just the information. (1) run out of stack is too much VLA. (2) Program does not end because calculation amount is rapidly increases as the array is large.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`memcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/) to compare your permutation to the desired one.

Also, be sure to match some `free`s to your `malloc`s when you're done with the data to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Notice that he returns the `malloc`ed pointer, so no need to free here at least.

Comment: @iharob That's correct, I'll adapt my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Not getting your point. So if I free it, I will loose the datasets generated. So I am assuming I can free it only once the final output is produced. Problem is I am not being able to understand how to generate that tree kind of structure.

Comment: @AnakataAndrese You're right, I missed the line `b[i] = copy;` and thought that you're pointer was lost. I think I'm not getting the point of your question. You're re-running `DoThis` on all outputs, so you should compare the results to `[1,2,4,3]` until its found or you've checked all possibilities. Or do you need the full tree structure in memory?

Comment: @Daerst No we don't run the full tree. We should stop when we find the desired element. That is why it is like a BFS I feel. I am very bad with C, so I am not being able to think of syntactical representation of the same though I can do it in Python .

[Here](http://pastebin.com/SupkJhdu) is the thing I tried in Python. And [here](http://pastebin.com/bP4tzGV1) is what I tried so far in C .

Comment: @AnakataAndrese I think that it can write a similar program if implemented the queue in C if the same as Python.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Is it? I am so bad with C. Any pointers/help would be great

Comment: @AnakataAndrese I have post that i rewrite Python version to C version.